# Android Canvas - Wanna learn how to make custom draws

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm willing to learn how to create my own draws with Android Canvas, I've noticed that there's some mathematics to learn how to deal with arcs, paths and points.

Does someone has material to share about that? I'm struggling to find some.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's all basic geometry and trigonometry.  If you get into scale vectors some basic linear algebra.

Comment: What would you recommend as a starting point?